Different version spring boot project as a dependency
I have a scenario where service A is running in spring boot 3.x version and i have a standalone common jar(service B)which is using spring boot 2.x version.
I want to use/add service B as a dependency in Service A.
When i do that i getting issues related to javax issues and many other bean injection issues. Because the service B is build using lower version of spring boot and java version.
Can anyone help on how to handle this?
Any suggestion will be of great help for me.
Note: Migrating service B to spring boot 3.x is not possible since that code is used at many other projects
I tried adding the service B as dependency but it was not working, not sure if multi module approach is suitable for this scenario

Spring Boot 2.x and 3.x are fundamentally incompatible. The only thing you could do is refactor the dependency to not contain any Spring/Java EE related code or refactor all projects to use Spring Boot 3.x (Spring Boot 2.x reached its end of (non-commercial) support). If you have to use Java EE/Jakarta EE types, you can use Eclipse transformer until all projects are migrated (but this doesn't work for anything Spring-specific).

Does this answer your question? Compatibility Spring Boot 3.x and Spring Boot 2.7.x?

Make a multi module build of your service A and integrate the part which is coming from the other project B (also migrate it to SB 3+).. later get the code back to your common project (if necessary)...and no dependency mixing will not work because SB 2.X and SB 3.X are different... also SB end of support is long known https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support why that late...

@dan1st you mean to say if i use eclipse transformer i can retain the service B to use spring 2.x and still the service A can be 3.x ia that right. Wil that work?

It should work if that service doesn't use anything from Spring or Hibernate and you should still update anything as quickly as possible.

@khmarbaise can you please help me understand more on your suggestion, i am still not getting how 2.x and 3.x will work because the bean containers will throw errors right dude incompatible version, some java class  might have unsupported imports right like javax in service B how do i handle that in this approach

@dan1st the service B i refered its a perfectly spring boot 2.x version which has all spring related dependencies

And that essentially means you cannot use it in a Spring Boot 3 project.

The only solution I've seen to this one, is to just simply create a branch of the depdendency service, that's using Spring Boot 3. It's far from ideal, as every new change would have to be merged into both branches, but hopefully it's a temporary solution anyways, because eventually, the other projects that depend on it should migrate to spring 6+.

In this case, "eventually" should mean "very soon" unless the maintainers like pain.

Yeah, sometimes the customer is a bottleneck for this, and it's hard to pressure them to do stuff when they're the ones with the dubloons. But it definitely should be a goal to resolve this ASAP.

@MárkHajdú i am not getting it you mean i need to create a branch for service B which is specific to me and migrate that to spring 3 and use it service A as a dependency is that what you Mean??
